# Apple Macbook Dual Monitor MST

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, displayport

I was looking into buying dual monitors for my Mid 2012 non-Retina MacBook. I really liked the looks of the [Dell UltraSharp 24 (U2414H)](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&sku=860-BBCG)

According to Dell, the Monitor supports MST for the Display Port.

Does my MacBook support this multi streaming technology?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately no, not at present (10.10.1).

Firstly, your MBP needs to support MST which is part of DisplayPort 1.2 - you can check your laptop's specifications as they may vary depending on which GPU option you went with when you purchased your MBP.

Secondly, even if your hardware supports it (many recent MBPs do) Apple [hasn't added](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6569158) support to OS X for this feature yet. Users who want MST on MBPs have been using bootcamp to boot to Windows which supports MST on the same hardware just fine.

Update (10-08-2015): It would appear as though (thanks to the links of those below) that MST support has been added in 10.10.3. Yay!

Comment: I don't know if this answer was correct at the time of writing but this Apple support doc clearly states that if your Mac hardware supports MST then OS X *should* support MST as well. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856

Comment: MST != multi-monitor chaining. It's used by chaining, but also used for high-res on a single display using multiple streams.

Comment: would love some facts regarding the current situation. Does OS X now support chaining through DP 1.2?

Comment: Same.. do MDT hubs work?  (StarTech MSTMDP123HD and MSTMDP123DP)

Comment: as of the 2020 (just got the new mac book pro), is there a way to have a daisy chain with the monitors? i only get them mirrorerd

Comment: 9/3/2020 - on macOS Catalina, while daisy chaining works (monitor powers), it is only supported in mirror mode with no way to change the child monitor resolution. Essentially MST is not supported by macOS even though confusingly supported by the hardware.

Answer (score 10):

As of 10.10.3 Apple does apparently support MST* on certain hardware:

> These Mac computers support multi-stream transport (MST) displays at 60 Hz:
>
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) and later,
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) and later,
> - Mac Pro (Late 2013),
> - iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) and later

From: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206587

*Unfortunately it does appear to be limited to an MST display that relies on multiple streams like the 4K MST Displays mentioned further down on the Apple Support page, and not MST for chaining multiple DP1.2 Displays as I haven't been able to find any information about this being possible.

From my own testing with the new MacBook Pro 2016 13" with two thunderbolts ports, a StarTech DP 1.2 USB Type-C to DisplayPort cable, two Dell U2414H and a standard DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable to chain with, the display on the end of the chain just mirrors the other display. This is with DisplayPort 1.2 enabled in the settings on both displays.

Which seems to confirm that MST DisplayPort daisy chaining on OSX 10.12.2 on the 2016 MacBook Pro line is unsupported, with no sign of it getting supported anytime soon.

Comment: trying just now to daisy chain 2 monitors with no success on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015). I enabled 1.2 dp option for the monitors, but I still get a mirrored image.

Comment: Yep, looks like Apple isn't interested in dealing with this in the near future, although it should be possible to support with a software/firmware update I think. A thunderbolt hub/splitter should do the job for now though.

Comment: Hub/spliters won't work actually because they are based on the same daisy chain principle.

Comment: They will, Apple explicitly supports daisy chaining with thunderbolt, not displayport though. So daisy chaining will only work with thunderbolt enabled monitors, but splitting with a hub will work for typical displayport monitors. You can drive two 2560x1440p monitors via a hub using a single thunderbolt port. I personally have two 1080p monitors connected via displayport to a StartTech Thunderbolt 2 hub. If you've got Thunderbolt 3 then you can drive 2 4K monitors over a single thunderbolt port with a hub.

Comment: Guys, try disabling MST on the last monitor in the chain. This is a requirement for Intel GPU's on Windows as it's used to signal the end of the chain, so may be a requirement for Mac as well.

Comment: Disabled MST on the second monitor and it still mirrors

Answer (score 6):

This doesn’t seem to be supported on the new 2017 MacBook Pro (A1708) with two Thunderbolt 3 ports.

However this is clearly not a hardware limitation since I am able to BootCamp into Windows where both external monitors work in extended mode (not mirrored). On the macOS Sierra side I can only have the two external displays mirror each other.

I have been using the IOGEAR GUD3C01 to test all of this.

Answer (score 3):

Not supported on 10.13.3 on 2018 (2017) 15" MBP using Kensington SD4600p dock.