# 3xHDMI out of a single Thunderbolt port - 2015 MBP

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I'm planning on purchasing 3 HDMI monitors to use as a workstation for my MBP. For the sake of ease and convenience, instead of using the native HDMI + 2 mini DP to HDMI adapters, is there any way to pull 3 HDMI connectors out of a single thunderbolt port?

I know that thunderbolt has the ability to daisy chain thunderbolt monitors together but I want to just break out 3 separate HDMI signals from the single port if thats possible, so that way I could just plug in power, the thunderbolt cable and that's it.

I've looked around the internet for a solution of some sort, and the only thing that has come even close is a thunderbolt hub such as the [Caldigit Thunderbolt Station](http://www.caldigit.com/thunderboltstation2/), but it only has 1 HDMI port. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You might want to extend your search to "mini DisplayPort to multiple HDMI"-adaptors. Thunderbolt IS NO DISPLAY CONNECTOR. It's mainly a combination of PCIe and DisplayPort lanes.

Comment: What model of MBP do you want to attach it to?

Comment: @MaxRied It's in the title, 2015 MBP. I'll try expanding my search, just didn't know exactly what to search for

Comment: Have a look at this. It is a very different question but with some statements of the Apple Support in the question that might be of interest: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/189542/7356

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an 'MST' hub.

https://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-Triple-Head-HDMI-Multi-Monitor-MST-Hub~MSTMDP123HD