# MacBook External Display Black

Tags: display

I have a 2018 MacBook 15inch using two HDMI to USB-C connectors.

Only one display ever shows an image, the other was black. What can I do?

*(I found the solution myself and tried to reply to this thread - [MacBook Pro detects external monitor but shows black screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25003/macbook-pro-detects-external-monitor-but-shows-black-screen). Unfortunately I don't have reputation to do so, so see my own answer below.)*

Comment: Great start Michael. Be sure to add the answer to this problem in the answer section. We love it when people get the answers set - self answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having troubles with a black display it could be that your Mac has onboard graphics and a dedicated graphics card.

My specific model is one of those and as soon as I turned off Automatic Graphics switching (Apple Icon > System Preferences > Energy Saver > Tick Box for Automatic Graphics Switching) the problem immediately ceased.

Ensure you do this for the relevant mode of use. You can change this setting for both using battery and being connected to power

Comment: Thank you for posting. All we ask is the question be brief and the answer be put as an answer.